# How to pivot in SQL for achieving multilevel headers

Tags: sql, aqua-data-studio

Pivot multilevel header without performing any aggregation

Unsure of how to really get this multilevel headings with no aggregation in the pivot, as you would notice the current and desired layout.

```
With pivot_data as
(
Select * from Table1
)
Select id, 3/31/2001, 6/30/2001, 9/30/2001, 12/31/2001, 3/31/2002, 6/30/2002, 9/30/2002, 12/31/2002
from pivot_data

Pivot(Max(Comm) For Dt in (3/31/2001, 6/30/2001, 9/30/2001, 12/31/2001, 3/31/2002, 6/30/2002, 9/30/2002, 12/31/2002)) P1
Pivot(Max(Norm)) For Dt in (3/31/2001, 6/30/2001, 9/30/2001, 12/31/2001, 3/31/2002, 6/30/2002, 9/30/2002, 12/31/2002)) P2
Pivot(Max(Team)) For Dt in (3/31/2001, 6/30/2001, 9/30/2001, 12/31/2001, 3/31/2002, 6/30/2002, 9/30/2002, 12/31/2002)) P3
```

I'm trying to achieve this layout:

```
    Comm    Comm    Comm    Comm    Norm    Norm    Norm    Norm
id  3/31/2018   6/30/2018   9/30/2018   12/31/2018  3/31/2018   6/30/2018   9/30/2018   12/31/2018
1   55  0   54  0   0   3   0   3
2   0   41  0   43  3   0   4   0


From Current layout:

id  Date        Comm    Norm
1   3/31/2018   55  
1   6/30/2018       3
1   9/30/2018   54  
1   12/31/2018      3
2   3/31/2018       3
2   6/30/2018   41  
2   9/30/2018       4
2   12/31/2018  43
```

Comment: "without performing any aggregation" - what does this mean?

Comment: Mysql does not support the pivot statement, so the above code cannot possibly related to mysql.

Comment: @CaiusJard just need to pivot without aggregating the columns Comm, Norm. I have shared the current and desired layout. Does that clarify? Pivot(Max(Comm)..(not sure if using Max is correct or not) Hence mentioned about no aggregation needed*

Comment: @Shadow In SQL we can do Pivot, if you know of a way to achieve the desired layout from the current layout (both layouts shared in the question). Is that confusing you? I can further clarify if the need be.

Comment: neeraj posted something that produces your desired output but it does need to use aggregation. is it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation this way:

```
select id,
    sum(case when Date = '3/31/2018' then Comm end) as 'Comm 3/31/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '6/30/2018' then Comm end) as 'Comm 6/30/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '9/30/2018' then Comm end) as 'Comm 9/30/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '12/31/2018' then Comm end) as 'Comm 12/31/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '3/31/2018' then Norm end) as 'Norm 3/31/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '6/30/2018' then Norm end) as 'Norm 6/30/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '9/30/2018' then Norm end) as 'Norm 9/30/2018',
    sum(case when Date = '12/31/2018' then Norm end) as 'Norm 12/31/2018'
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: i thought this, it's just where he says "without performing any aggregation" that puzzles me. the same can be performed with multiple joins i suppose

Comment: @CaiusJard - Confusing language "Unsure of how to really get this multilevel headings with no aggregation in the pivot". I offered this solution as it does conditional aggregation to achieve what a pivot will achieve.

Comment: @CaiusJard When I say no aggregation I mean for columns Comm and Norm. Sorry if it confused you. Do you know how to achieve this using PIVOT function in SQL?

Comment: @NeerajAgarwal I get what your code is, but it gives as one column header Comm 3/31/2018. I want to keep this separately as you would notice on the desired output I have shared above, Any solution to that using PIVOT? And yes, When I say no aggregation I mean for columns Comm and Norm. Sorry if it confused you.

Comment: Neeraj's code produces exactly the output you asked for. Are you saying you want a newline character in the header so that Comm is on a different line to 3/31/2018?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I don't think in Column alias we can add a new line character. Is there a way?

Comment: You can but why would you? The column header simply serves as some way for the front end program to identify the column of data when its outputting. Formatting of column headers, tabling of data, font size and colour etc should be done by the front end reports tool

Comment: @CaiusJard Can't agree more! But, when we need multilevel headers while pivoting using SQL, how do we get that?

Comment: What's a multi level header?

Comment: when you have more than 1 rows as column names* meaning 2 different names for one column for reporting purposes*